# Hook with props

Tags: reactjs

My Home page is a simple function component, when the user reach the page, I have to invoke a props callback (to clear the parent's state).

I need somethink like that:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.props.handleChange("ticket",{});
  }
```

I read I can do that with hooks, `useEffect`, but I'm not sure about the way to invoke the `handleChange` prop.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //handleChange('ticket', {});
  });
```

Home component:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <Hello />
        <div css={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <Button to="/departments" styles={buttonStyles}>
            Next
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Parent `handleChange` function:

```
 makeHandleChange = (pageName, change) => {
    this.setState({
      ticket: { ...this.state.ticket, [pageName]: change },
    });
  };
```

Edit:

```
 export default function Home(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('test');
    props.handleChange('departments', {});
    props.handleChange('categories', {});
    props.handleChange('subCategories', {});
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <Hello />
        <div css={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <Button to="/departments" styles={buttonStyles}>
            Next
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: the `useEffect` hook runs after every component update, so as long as your button click triggers a lifecycle update, the hook will run at the end of the render and call your parent function

Answer (score 0):

To mimic `componentDidMount` and call the function from props, do it as follows:

```
export default function Home(props) {
    useEffect(() => {
       props.handleChange("ticket",{});
    }, []); // <-- This empty array is important

   /* ... */
}
```

Some more explanation:

The second argument tells the hook what it should react and update to. You can listen to state variables created by `useState` and also props.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {}, [props.id, state]); // Listen to state changes and prop changes
```

If you omit the second argument, the hook will trigger on all changes (state and props).

```
// This will trigger on mount and all changes
useEffect(() => {})
```

Leaving it as an empty array will only trigger the effect once, and that is on mount of the component (after first render).

Some more information and reference: [Using the Effect Hook - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer, for some reason the callback `props.handleChange("ticket",{});` causes an infinite loop, any idea why?

Comment: @user3378165 Would you mind sharing your current code where you render `Home` and assign it props and add it to your question?